# Moving through JavaScript objects and increment by one on each click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to move to the next month on click of a div i have the months store as objects in months = []; but when i use ++ it just repeats the same month why? heres my JS:

```
var newdate = new Date();
var getnewmonthword = newdate.getMonth();
var i = 0;
months = [];
months[0] = ('january');
months[1] = ('february');
months[2] = ('march');
months[3] = ('apri');
months[4] = ('may');
months[5] = ('june');
months[6] = ('july');
months[7] = ('august');
months[8] = ('september');
months[9] = ('october');
months[10] = ('november');
months[11] = ('december');
var countemonth = getnewmonthword;
var myMonthName = months[countemonth];

$('#test span').replaceWith('<span>' + myMonthName + '</span>')
$('#addone').on('click', function () {
    alert('fred');
    countemonth++;
    //months[++i];
   // $('#test span').replaceWith('<span>' + countemonth + '</span>')
    $('#test span').replaceWith('<span>' + myMonthName + '</span>')
});
```

if i uncomment the countemonth replaceWith it does actually ad 1 to each but it just returns the number not the name...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your `myMonthName` on every click , like this:

```
$('#addone').on('click', function () {    
    countemonth = ((countemonth+1) % months.length);
    myMonthName = months[countemonth];
    $('#test span').replaceWith('<span>' + myMonthName + '</span>')
});
```

Comment: Doh, you beat me by a second!

Comment: @vimes1984 it is ok , it happens to everyone

Comment: That modulus was a must,wasn't it ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that you mainly forgot to put a line

```
myMonthName = months[countemonth];
```

Follows the complete solution:

```
var newdate = new Date();
var getnewmonthword = newdate.getMonth();
var i = 0;
months = [];
months[0] = ('january');
months[1] = ('february');
months[2] = ('march');
months[3] = ('apri');
months[4] = ('may');
months[5] = ('june');
months[6] = ('july');
months[7] = ('august');
months[8] = ('september');
months[9] = ('october');
months[10] = ('november');
months[11] = ('december');
var countemonth = getnewmonthword;
var myMonthName = months[countemonth];

$('#test span').replaceWith('<span>' + myMonthName + '</span>')
$('#addone').on('click', function () {
    countemonth++;
    if (countemonth>=months.length) 
        countemonth = 0;

    myMonthName = months[countemonth];
    $('#test span').replaceWith('<span>' + myMonthName + '</span>')
});
```

[Fiddler Ready Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/FteJD/)

Answer (score 2):

myMonthName is in global scope. Move it into your click handler:

```
$('#addone').on('click', function () {
    alert('fred');
    countemonth++;
    var myMonthName = months[countemonth];        
    $('#test span').replaceWith('<span>' + myMonthName + '</span>')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
var myMonthName = months[countemonth];
```

You get from your array the value at the index with the *current* value of `countemonth`. It is not a live connection. If you change `countemonth` later (as you do in your click handler) it won't automagically update `myMonthName`. You need to basically repeat that assignment in your click handler:

```
countemonth++;
myMonthName = months[countemonth];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that each click should set `myMonthName` variable?

This sentence...

```
var myMonthName = months[countemonth];
```

...happens once!

Summary: you need to set the whole variable each time the click event handler is called!!

```
$('#addone').on('click', function () {
    alert('fred');
    countemonth++;

    // Now will work!
    var myMonthName = months[countemonth];

    $('#test span').replaceWith('<span>' + myMonthName + '</span>')
});
```

Anyway, I would change the array declaration to:

```
var months = ["January", "February"]; // ... and the rest of months
```

Also, why replace the `span`?

<strike>$('#test span').replaceWith('' + myMonthName + '')</strike>

```
$("#test span").text(myMonthName); // Better!!!!!
```

And, at the end of the day, you could store the jQuery object as follows:

```
var monthNameElement = $('#test span');
```

...and later reuse everywhere, even in the click handler:

```
var monthNameElement = $('#test span');

$('#addone').on('click', function () {
    alert('fred');
    countemonth++;

    // Now will work!
    var myMonthName = months[countemonth];
    monthNameElement.text(myMonthName);
});
```

Note that the last suggestion saves your browser from querying the same element twice! And if you do like I showed in the above samples, when you need to use the same element a lot of times, storing a reference in a variable and use everywhere may speed up your Web page a lot!